# var app inside of Main Module not recognized by other components inside of the same module

Tags: angularjs, typescript, lazy-loading

I have a main module that is creating my angular.module called 'FormTest'.  Inside of the FormTest module I have a directive called 'ji-Text'. I have lazy loading going on to load the directives and views into a .js file (not as significant).  The problem is that inside of my directive, "app" is not recognized.  But I am not sure why because it is inside of the same module "FormTest".  The error I get is TS2304 "Cannot find name 'app'.

**Directive**

```
module FormTest {
    app.directive('jiText', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: { name: '@' },
            templateUrl: 'FormText/views/ji-Text.html'
        }
    });
}
```

**Main Module**

```
module FormTest {
    "use strict";

        //Create the formTest module

        var app = angular.module('FormTest', ['dx'])
        app.config(confirm);
    }
```

**Lazy Loading**

```
                .state('FormTest', <ng.ui.IState> {
                    url: '/formTest',
                    templateUrl: 'FormTest/FormTest.html',
                    loadCtl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load('js/FormTest.js');
                    }]
                })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access modules this way! You must use `angular.module` to get It at the context. And, `strict mode` will prevent you to use any use undeclared variables. Just change to:

```
module FormTest {
    angular
     .module('FormTest') //Gets the FormTest Module
     .directive('jiText', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: { name: '@' },
            templateUrl: 'FormText/views/ji-Text.html'
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  But how would I do this with multiple directives using the same 'FormTest' module, if I want to keep each one in their own .ts file.  Ex: jiText.ts, jiButton.ts....etc all using the same angular module and the same .Net module.

Comment: That does fix it so I will mark as answered but I feel like there should be a way to still have an app.ts file that has a .NET module and an angular.module and then be able to use the angular.module in other .ts files and have all of them lazy loaded into one .js file under the same .NET module.

Comment: @Tim It's a bad Idea create a global variable for app. The Style guide says that you should aways call the angular.module to get the module.